# Python Tkinter Text Scroll Past Last Line

Tags: python, text, scroll, tkinter

In programs like Sublime Text, users are able to scroll past the last line of their text. Like so:[image]

I was wondering if there was any way this could be achieved with Tkinter.
I'm not really sure how to go about even testing this and searching yields naught.
None the less, I find this to be a useful feature and helps me not get lost in a wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, other than to add a bunch of blank lines at the end.